# Using Linq to determine if there is more than 2 distinct items in a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that contains a list of another class which has a property that I want to check if it has more than one distinct value.

e.g

```
public class BasketModel
{
    public BasketModel()
    {
        BasketOrderLines = new List<BasketOrderLine>();
    }
    .
    . 
    .

 public class BasketOrderLine
{
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
               .
               .
```

Given a basket model object I want to find out if there are more than one distinct value in the ProductType.

e.g If all Product Types are "A" then that would be false, if 3 products are of type "A" and one is of type "B" then this would be true.

Cheers
Macca

Comment: What have you tried? What was the issue? `Where` condition based on `Distinct` + `Count` sounds pretty obvious here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title: *"more than two distinct"*, your question body: *"more than one distinct"*

If the title is a typo:

```
bool notDistinctTypes = theBasket.BasketOrderLine
    .Select(o => o.ProductType)
    .Distinct()
    .Skip(1)
    .Any();
```

This doesn't need to enumerate all items to find out if there is more than one `ProductType`.

Comment: Good solution with `Skip(n).Any()` - it will not iterate all items

Comment: Err... Distinct() has to iterate all items.

Comment: @buffjape: `Distinct` doesn't have to itterate *all* the items, but when iterating return distinct ones only; see https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4ab583c7d8e84d6d

Comment: @buffjape I mean iterating all items in output sequence (after Distinct) - you don't need `Count()` here, because task is not to find total number of distinct items. Task is checking whether there is more than N distinct items.

Comment: @buffjape: no, [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't need to enumerate all items to remove duplicates. It's implemented using deferred execution. So only if there is just one producttype it has to enumerate all.

Comment: Yes Tim, Title was a typo. :-). Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Does this basket contains three or more types
public bool HasSeveralTypes(BasketModel basket)
{
    if (basket == null)
        return false;

    int differentTypes = basket.BasketOrderLines 
                               .Select(l => l.ProductType)
                               .Distinct()
                               .Count();

    return (differentTypes > 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
Public bool CheckDistinct (){
    var res = basketOrderLines.Select(o => o.ProductType).Distinct ().Count ();

    return res > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, here's one:

```
public class BasketModel
{
    public BasketModel()
    {
        BasketOrderLines = new List<BasketOrderLine>();
    }

    public bool HasMulitpleDistinctProducts
    {
        get
        {
            if (!BasketOrderLines.Any())
            {
                return true; // or false?
            }
            return BasketOrderLines.Select(b => b.ProductType).Distinct().Count() > 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a type extension you can call directly from your list. The pros of this code is to be adaptable to any type implementing `IEquals` and not only `string` + kick to use from your code.

The code :

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static bool fDistinctProductType(this List<BasketOrderLine> lstToAnalyse)
    {
        BasketOrderLine ProductTypeA = lstToAnalyse.FirstOrDefault();
        if (ProductTypeA == null) // It's null when lstToAnalyse is empty
            return false;

        BasketOrderLine ProductTypeB = lstToAnalyse.Where(b => b.ProductType.Equals(ProductTypeA.ProductType)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (ProductTypeB == null) // It's null when it doesn't exists a distinct ProductType
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

How to call:

```
List<BasketOrderLine> lst = new List<BasketOrderLine>();
// Add element to list

if (lst.fDistinctProductType())
{
    // DO Something
}
```